# iOS8 Specific Code - Making Apps Ready

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I have an app which uses push notifications. The code has apparently changed to register for those notifications in iOS8. I have added some additional code which tests the version currently running and uses the correct code for iOS8 and the correct code < iOS8.

My problem is during build it naturally complains about the iOS 8 code and won't allow me to archive and submit to the stores. I just want to make sure the app works smoothly after iOS8 goes live.

Can anybody suggest where I am going wrong? I have been on Google for longer than I want to admit!

Thanks

Comment: Apple wont allow you to build using Xcode beta version. What is your xcode version?

Comment: I am using xcode 5 but code that is introduced in iOS8. There must be a way to fix your apps ahead of the release so they continue to function?

Comment: can you show me the new code added for iOS 8?

Comment: if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificationTypes categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationTypes];
    }

Comment: notificationTypes  is already set above this block